# My char vector is saving the same value in every position

Tags: c, linux, shell, vector

Im trying to make a shell in linux. I need to save every command the user typed and when the user wants to see the history Ill show him the last 10 commands. Im using a char* historial[10]; but when the user type the second command it is saving in historial[0] and historial[1] the same thing. So if I type 10 different commands, it will save the last command 10 times. I dont know what Im doing wrong.
PS: my condition in the do while is not working neither.

```
int ejecutarCom(char* comando)
{ //executes the command
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    int aux = 0;
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        perror("Error");
        return -1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        aux = execlp(comando, comando, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return aux;
}

char* historial[10]; //history vector
int cantidad = 0, tamano = 10; //quantity & size
void guardarEnHistorial(char* c)
{ //saves every command
    if (cantidad < tamano)
    {
        historial[cantidad] = c;
    }
    if (cantidad == tamano)
    {
        cantidad = 0;
        historial[cantidad] = c;
    }
    cantidad++;
}

void verHistorial()
{ //shows history
    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (historial[0] == NULL)
            break;
        else if (historial[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        else
            printf("%i: %s\n", i, historial[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char* comando = (char*) malloc(1024);
    int x = 1;
    do
    {
        printf("%s ", prompt);
        fflush(stdout);
        fgets(comando, sizeof(comando), stdin);
        comando[strcspn(comando, "\n")] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", comando);
        if (strcmp(comando, "hist") == 0)
        {
            verHistorial();
        }
        else
        {
            x = ejecutarCom(comando);
            guardarEnHistorial(comando);
            printf("%i\n", x);
        }
    } while (x != -1);
```

Comment: Is it possible that you save pointers to the same buffer all the time? Then even if it contains something new each time, dereferencing it will always end up with the same buffers content, which at the end is of course identical via all pointers...

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you would use english names for your variables and functions. And would it be possible to slim down the code to just the problem you have? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Yunnosch hit the nail on the head. You are storing the value of `comando` in  `historial`. You need to make copy of  string held in `comando` when you store the copy in `historial`. Lookup `strdup` and use it to make a copy of `comando` and store the copy in `historial`.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your main function like below. Every location of your history array is pointing to same memory location hence you are getting the same information in every location. You have to allocate memory for each command like below:-

```
int main(){
 char* comando=(char*) malloc(1024);
 int x=1;
do{
   printf("%s ",prompt);
   fflush (stdout);
   fgets(comando,sizeof(comando),stdin); 
   comando[strcspn(comando, "\n")] = '\0';
   printf("%s\n",comando);
   if(strcmp(comando,"hist")==0){
     verHistorial();}
   else{
     x=ejecutarCom(comando);
     guardarEnHistorial(comando);
     comando=(char*) malloc(1024);// You need to allocate memory to store 
//each history records. Also consider whether you really need 1024 bytes of memory make it small
    printf("%i\n",x);
 }}while(x!=-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing a *pointer* to the command buffer, not the command itself. As the address of the command buffer doesn't change, but its contents does, every history entry will point to the same command buffer and thus will show the same command:

```
char* historial[10];          // history vector has only pointers
//...
    historial[cantidad] = c;  // stores a pointer
```

The following allocates and frees memory as appropriate:

```
void guardarEnHistorial(char* c)
{ //saves every command
    if (cantidad == tamano) cantidad = 0;
    if (historial[cantidad]) free(historial[cantidad]);
    historial[cantidad]= malloc(strlen(c)+1);
    strcpy(historial[cantidad], c);
    cantidad++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I dont know what Im doing wrong.

You are observing this behavior because the `char` pointers of `historial` array are pointing to same memory location `comando`. Check this statement of your program:

```
guardarEnHistorial(comando);
```

and in the `guardarEnHistorial ()` function, you are doing:

```
historial[cantidad] = c;
```

Any changes you make to `comando` will reflect to all the members of `historial` array in which you have *saved* the command.

You can use `strdup()` to resolve this issue. Replace this:

```
guardarEnHistorial(comando);
```

with this:

```
guardarEnHistorial(strdup(comando));
                    ^^^^
```

The [strdup()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) function returns a pointer to a new string which is a       duplicate of the string passed to it. `strdup()` allocates a memory for the new string using `malloc` and returns its pointer. Make sure to free it using `free()` once you are done with it. Like when inserting into `historial` array, you are rotating the insertion if the condition `cantidad == tamano` meets. Here, you need to free the element first and then insert the new element into the array otherwise there is a memory leaks in your program.